# script not reading last line of a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i have a file created in windows using notepad:

```
    26453215432460
    23543265235421

    38654365876325


    12354152435243
```

I have a script which will read every line, and create a command like below in other file for every line and will not consider blank lines:

```
    CRE:EQU,264532154324600,432460,1;
```

Now if I save my input file after hitting enter after the last line of number `12354152435243`, then the output file consists the command above corresponding to all numbers(including the last `12354152435243`:

```
    CRE:EQU,264532154324600,432460,1;
    CRE:EQU,235432652354210,235421,1;
    CRE:EQU,386543658763250,876325,1;
    CRE:EQU,123541524352430,435243,1;
```

but if I save the file, without hitting enter after the last number is keyed in i.e after this `12354152435243`, then after the script executes, I don't see the output file have the command for the last number:

```
    CRE:EQU,264532154324600,432460,1;
    CRE:EQU,235432652354210,235421,1;
    CRE:EQU,386543658763250,876325,1;
```

Can somebody explain the error in the code:

```
    while read LINE
    do
    [ -z "$LINE" ] && continue
    IMEI=`echo $LINE | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g'`
    END_SERIAL=`echo $IMEI | cut -c9- | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g'`
    echo "CRE:EQU,${IMEI}0,${END_SERIAL},${list},,${TODAY};" >> /apps/ins/list.out
    done < "${FILE_NAME}"
```

kindly help

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with Windows vs. *nix line endings. (Probably not, but you never know...) Try opening the file in a hex editor like HexFiend, and look at the last character.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something with a carriage return or `\n` character

Comment: Well, you might be able to change the line ending to a Unix line ending instead of a Windows line ending.

Comment: I have already a `dos2unix` added in my script, after the input file fetched. Do you mean, that won't take care of it ?

Comment: @Siddharth any luck with the below answer?

Comment: Notepad has the stupid idea that the last line doesn't need *any* kind of terminator. What it saves, if you don't make sure to manually end the file with a newline, is technically not a valid text file since text files are composed of lines with terminators.

Comment: Yes, I am already getting that :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script read missing last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
grep . "${FILE_NAME}" | while read LINE
```

or

```
while read LINE
do
....
done < <(grep . "${FILE_NAME}")
```

The grep is less sensible to line-ending, and you will get empty-line skip for a free... :)

Honestly, never tried windows, all above is OK for unix...

**EDIT Explanation:**

make the next file:

```
echo -n -e 'line\n\nanother\nno line ending here>' >file.txt
```

the file contains 4 lines (although the last "line" is not a "correct" one)

```
line

another
no line ending here>
```

Usual shell routines, as `read` or `wc` looking for line ending. Therefore,

```
$ wc -l file.txt 
         3 file.txt
```

When you grepping for `''` (empty string) the grep returns every line where found the string, so

```
$ grep '' file.txt
```

prints

```
line

another
no line ending here>
```

When grep prints out the found lines - ensures than one `\n' exists at the end, so

```
$ grep '' file.txt | wc -l
```

returns

```
4
```

therefore, for these situations, is better to use `grep` with `-c` (count) and not `wc`.

```
$ grep -c '' file.txt
4
```

Now, the `.` dot. The dot mean *any character*. So, when you grepping for a `.`, you get all lines what contain **at least one** character. *And therefore, it will skip all lines what doesn't contain any character = skips empty lines*. So,

```
$ grep . file.txt
line
another
no line ending here>
```

again, with added line ending to the last line (and skipped the empty line). Remember, the  (space) is character too, so when the line contains only one space it is NOT EMPTY. Counting non-empty lines

```
$ grep . file.txt | wc -l
      3
```

or faster

```
$ grep -c . file.txt
3
```

Comment: Excellent this is working. Would you be kind enough, just to explain the logic of why I'm greppin `.` from the `$FILE` . Many thanks anyway for this trick. Cheers

Comment: @Siddharth added explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `help read` it says for `-d delim continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline`.

So read will continue until it hits a `\n` or if you specify `-d delim`.

So you probably need to change the delim or you can try `read -e`

Comment: `read -e` is not working for me `echo -n $'a\nb' | while read -e x ; do echo $x ; done`
`-ksh: read: -e: unknown option Usage: read [-ACprsv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n nchar] [-N nchar] [var?prompt] [var ...]`
Also using `delim` with `-d` option will increase my code to quiet a few lines, as i have to first copy the input file with a character acting as the delimeter for every non-blank line, then i have to feed it to `read -d delim`.

Answer (score 1):

read will read untill a new line has been found and when it finds a new line, it will return you the line. But if the file ends without a new line, read treats this as an error. So, even if read has set the returning variable with the line read till now, the return code of `read` is set to indicate an error. Now the `while read ...` this loop body will only executes if the command executes with a success which is not a case here. Thus you miss the last line.

For overcoming this , you can change the condition to also check the returning variable is empty or not. Hence the condition succeeds even if read fails, as the variable is already set till the end of the file.

This is not related to line ending in different OS, i mean it's somehow related, but the exact root cause is always the `read` fails to find a new line at the end of the line/file, and the last line is missing the loop body.

Below is an example

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ echo -ne 'hello\nthere' > log
[[bash_prompt$]]$ while read line; do  echo $line; done < log
hello
[[bash_prompt$]]$ while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do  echo $line; done < log
hello
there
[[bash_prompt$]]$
```

Answer (score 0):

`read` nees the end of line to read the input. Try

```
echo -n $'a\nb' | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

It only prints `a`.

Comment: `read -e` is not working for me `echo -n $'a\nb' | while read -e x ; do echo $x ; done`
`-ksh: read: -e: unknown option`
`Usage: read [-ACprsv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n nchar] [-N nchar] [var?prompt] [var ...]` Does it not work for k-shell ?

Comment: @Siddharth: The `-e` was not important, I was just trying what nkon suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent script not reading last line of a file:

```
cat "somefile" | { cat ; echo ; } | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/