# Why does unix while read not read last line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My script

```
export IFS=":"

cat hello | while read a b c d; do
    echo $a,$b,$c,$d
done
```

My file `hello`

```
1:1:1:1
2:2:2:2
3:3:3:3
```

My output

```
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
```

If I put a blank line after `3:3:3:3` in `hello` then the output becomes

```
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3
```

Anyone know how I can fix this problem so I don't need to put a blank line at the end of `hello`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What's happening is, the `read` command fails when *the input is not terminated with a newline*. Since the newline character is missing at the end of your file, the `read` fails, so the last iteration of the `while` loop is skipped.

If you don't want to / cannot make sure that your input file has a newline at the end, you can group your `cat` with an `echo` to give the *appearance* of an input terminated by newline, for example like this:

```
{ cat hello; echo; } | while read a b c d; do
    echo $a,$b,$c,$d
done
```

or like this:

```
(cat hello; echo) | while read a b c d; do
    echo $a,$b,$c,$d
done
```

Answer (score 10):

[This is an extensive reading for the question *why?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916758/3744681)

If you don't want to put a new line at the end, you can do this:

```
while IFS=: read -r a b c d || [ -n "$a" ]; 
do     
echo $a,$b,$c,$d; 
done < file
```

Or using `grep`:

```
while IFS=: read -r a b c d; 
do     
echo $a,$b,$c,$d; 
done < <(grep "" filee)
```

Note:

1. There's no need to use cat with while loop.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: This worked best for me thank you. @janos' answer works too, but uses a subshell - anything set inside the while loop in their answer lives only in that scope (e.g. if you're exporting variables from a file to use outside of the while loop - you want to use this answer)

Answer (score 8):

There exists a not very well-known, nasty hack to append a missing final newline to a text stream if and only if it's missing:

```
sed '$a\'
```

See [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file) on unix.stackexchange, for example.

Comment: There are lots of those. Others include `grep ^`, `awk 1`, `paste`

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely due to absence of newline character after last line in your input file.

Run this command to find out:

```
cat -vte hello
```

And see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is probably missing a newline (`\n`) on the last line.
You can prove this by printing the residual values of `$a` etc, like so

```
while IFS=: read a b c d; 
do     
echo $a,$b,$c,$d; 
done < hello  
echo $a,$b,$c,$d
```

Fix the file.
Also, you should be able to set `IFS` specifically for the `read` as shown above. And no need to `cat` the file either, just use input redirection as shown