# Generate two Outputfile with different values using Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, output

I am generating 2 output file from input wile using **shell script**. One successfully creating but 2nd file  having only one row .

Suppose I have one input file(csv) with 3 rows.It generate one output file with some other information with all 3 rows But 2 nd out put file only generating with some other value with 1 row value only .
Here Is my code :

```
#! /bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    INPUT_FILE="$1" 
    echo 'Brand,Width (mm),Height (mm),Depth (mm)' > mug.csv 
    echo 'Design Name, Type,Product ' > mugsku.csv 
    while read Brand designname width height types 
    do  
        echo "$brand.$width,$height,$depth" >> mug.csv
        echo "$designname,$types,$ptype" > mugsku.csv 
    done < $INPUT_FILE
else
    echo "No argument passed.Pass valid file name"
fi
```

Input file name I am passing as an **argument**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the below line, which over-writes (`>` operator) the file on every iteration of the `for-loop`.

```
echo "$designname,$types,$ptype" > mugsku.csv
```

You should have been using the append operator(`>>`) like,

```
echo "$designname,$types,$ptype" >> mugsku.csv
```

You can do a few-more optimizations over your script,

1. Double-quote your variables, e.g. as `"$INPUT_FILE"`
2. Add a `-r` flag to `read` to make it more robust.

Comment: Please help me in one more thing.I am reading csv file it reads only 2 instead of three.It read 3rd line if i give enter in last row in input file.Can you please tell me what will be the reason for this.

Comment: @Urvashi: Can you explain it a bit more? I can't understand it clearly

Comment: Got solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010741/why-does-unix-while-read-not-read-last-line.Thanks you very much once again