# Why does read throw an error in bash but works fine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ifs

This bash script writes an array to a file and then reads the file back into a different array. (This is useful for array-based communication between scripts.) However, a strange, non-reported error is trapped by the `IFS` line (line 12). ***Why?***

```
#!/bin/bash

# eso-error-ic

trap 'echo Error trapped, with code $?, on line ${LINENO}' ERR

# write data to a file
arr=(0 abc) && printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" > eso.out

# read data from the file into an array
# throws an error!!
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a new_arr < eso.out

# but it worked...
echo ${new_arr[0]}
echo ${new_arr[1]}
```

Script output:

```
Error trapped, with code 1, on line 12
0
abc
```

What's missing is any sort of message displayed when the error is produced. All you get is the message from the trap but no message about *what* the error **is**.

In other words, the IFS/read line produces an error, which is trapped, but no error message is displayed and the line properly reads the file into an array variable. It works, reports no error, but an "error" is trapped.

If you comment out the trap line OR switch to the command/eval/cat approach to reading a file into an array (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array#11393884)), no error is trapped. Here is what the command/eval/cat line would look like for this script (to replace line 12):

```
IFS=$'\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval 'new_arr=($(cat eso.out))'
```

Comment: I can repro with Bash 3.2.57(1) on MacOS High Sierra with simply `read -d '' variable <<<"moo"; echo $?`

Comment: Wow. Much simpler repo! I've reproduced it on Bash 4 on CentOS 6/7, RHEL 6/7, and Bash 3 & 4 on Apple Darwin 17.3 (High Sierra).

Comment: Cross site duplicate with detailed explanation : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80045/read-a-array-d-n-foo-exit-code-1

Comment: By the way, `set -e` and/or ERR traps are generally considered a bad idea. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry; or the list of incompatibilities between different shells' implementations of `set -e` (and, related, the extent to which its behavior isn't intuitively predictable) [here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/).

Comment: Related question (identical cause) on this site: [Why does UNIX while read not read last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010741/why-does-unix-while-read-not-read-last-line)

Comment: BTW, *in general*, I'd suggest `readarray -t new_arr <eso.dat` (if you don't need compatibility with bash pre-4.x) -- except when you're reading from a process substitution instead of a file, such that passing through that process's success or failure through to the success of the `read` by appending a trailing or NUL or not is an actively useful capability.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the trouble with `readarray` is, it is not available on bash 4.4 on Apple, which is the platform I tend to test on before going to the server. Why? No idea.

Comment: @DarkerIvy, it's absolutely available with MacPorts or Homebrew builds of bash 4.4 on MacOS; I use it there all the time. I suspect that your script is instead being interpreted by the bash 3.2 that Apple shipped, and suggest running `echo $BASH_VERSION` *in the same shell interpreter context that generates any message about `readarray` not being available*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy once again, you are absolutely right. shebang and profile pointing to two different versions. It _is_ available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from not receiving the delimiter that `read` was expecting.  I get the same with

```
read -d x variable <<<"hello"
```

If I change the input to `"hellox"` the error disappears.

As mentioned by @Aserre, a detailed analys is at our [Unix & Linux sister site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80045/read-a-array-d-n-foo-exit-code-1) and as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy a common workaround is

```
read variable || [[ $variable ]]
```

which is used even without `-d` to cope with files which might lack the final terminating newline.

Comment: You can take the uncertainty out of this answer. It's spot-on, and is why `read x || [[ $x ]]` is an idiom when tolerating a missing delimiter is desired.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the explanation. I still say it is an error of the error to exit 1 without stderr-ing anything.