# Bash read ignores leading spaces

Tags: bash

I have file `a.txt` with following content

```
    aaa
    bbb
```

When I execute following script:

```
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < a.txt > b.txt
```

generated `b.txt` contains following

```
aaa
bbb
```

It is seen that the leading spaces of lines have got removed. How can I preserve leading spaces?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is covered in the Bash FAQ entry on [reading data line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Trimming).

> The read command modifies each line read; by default it removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, or any whitespace characters present in IFS). If that is not desired, the IFS variable has to be cleared:
>
> ```
> # Exact lines, no trimming
> while IFS= read -r line; do
>   printf '%s\n' "$line"
> done < "$file"
> ```

As Charles Duffy correctly points out (and I'd missed by focusing on the `IFS` issue); if you want to see the spaces in your output you also need to quote the variable when you use it or the shell will, once again, drop the whitespace.

Notes about some of the other differences in that quoted snippet as compared to your original code.

The use of the `-r` argument to `read` is covered in a single sentence at the top of the previously linked page.

> The -r option to read prevents backslash interpretation (usually used as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines). Without this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded. You should almost always use the -r option with read.

As to using `printf` instead of `echo` there the behavior of `echo` is, somewhat unfortunately, not portably consistent across all environments and the differences can be awkward to deal with. `printf` on the other hand is consistent and can be used entirely robustly.

Comment: If you do not give `read` any arguments to use to hold the input (relying on the default variable `REPLY`), no whitespace is stripped and you can omit the modification to `IFS`. That is, `while read -r; do printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"; done < "$file"`

Comment: I'm not sure; it doesn't seem to be documented as far as I can tell. It makes some sense if you think of it as zero arguments require splitting the line into zero fields, meaning there is no use for `IFS`. (That assumes you accept that splitting a line into one field is still a split, albeit a degenerate one.) In any case, it is a `bash`ism; POSIX `read` requires at least one argument.

Comment: @chepner: `man bash` says about `$REPLY` (emphasis mine): "Set to the _line_ of input read by the read builtin  command  when no arguments are supplied." Thus, the idea is to read the _whole line as is_, as opposed to _splitting it into fields_. What is counter-intuitive, however, is that you still also have to specify `-r` to avoid backslash interpretation.
Note that the (rarely used) `select` construct - where splitting into fields doesn't even enter the picture - also sets `$REPLY` to whatever the user entered (_invariably_ backslash-interpreted, but otherwise also as is).

Comment: As for why `-r` is still needed to suppress backslash interpretation even when using just `$REPLY` (not specifying any variable names): Not specifying `-r` potentially reads _multiple_ lines at once (joined without newlines), if the input has `\ `-escaped newlines; if using just `$REPLY` _implied_ `-r`, this multi-line behavior would not be available.

Comment: Very interesting discussion. What this seems to imply to me actually is the potential need for a distinction between `-r` and `-r`-for-newlines-only.

Comment: `read`'s default behavior allows _line continuation_ by ending a line with `\ ` and continuing it on the next line (both the `\ ` and the newline are _discarded_). This is rarely useful, except maybe for _interactive_ input, and, given that the `\ ` in _any_ `\<char>` pair is discarded, typically surprises the user.
I think the real issue here is that the behavior of `-r` (_always_ read _only one_ line, keep all backslashes) should have been the _default_ behavior all along, but the current behavior is POSIX-mandated, so we're stuck with it. (cont'd in next comment)

Comment: (cont'd from prev. comment) The upshot is: as your quote states, you'll almost always want to use `-r`, and I don't see a real need to support line continuation with `-r`. While not quite the same, if you do have the need to read across lines in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, you can use `read -r d <delimChar> …`,  which does have the advantage that the newlines don't have to (and shouldn't be) `\ `-escaped.

Comment: Maybe`while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];` is the final solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/31398490/456536

Comment: Re: "You should almost always use the -r option with read.": then why `-r` is not enabled by default?

Answer (score 19):

There are several problems here:

- Unless `IFS` is cleared, `read` strips leading and trailing whitespace.
- `echo $line` string-splits and glob-expands the contents of `$line`, breaking it up into individual words, and passing those words as individual arguments to the `echo` command. Thus, even with IFS cleared at `read` time, `echo $line` would still discard leading and trailing whitespace, and change runs of whitespace between words into a single space character each. Additionally, a line containing only the character `*` would be expanded to contain a list of filenames.
- `echo "$line"` is a significant improvement, but still won't correctly handle values such as `-n`, which it treats as an echo argument itself. `printf '%s\n' "$line"` would fix this fully.
- `read` without `-r` treats backslashes as continuation characters rather than literal content, such that they won't be included in the values produced unless doubled-up to escape themselves.

Thus:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Comment: Good advice, but the two-character sequence `\n` does _not_ result in a _newline_, it results in _literal `n`_. By contrast, a `\  `-escaped _actual_ newline causes `read` to read the _following_ line also, and to directly append it to the current one (discarding the `\ ` and the newline). A `\ ` before any other character is simply discarded.

Comment: Another way of describing the behavior of `read` without `-r`: the input is parsed in the same way a bareword with individually `\ `-escaped characters is parsed by the (POSIX) shell itself (e.g., as part of an argument list), as described at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01 
and essentially duplicated in `read`'s POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html.

Comment: Thank you -- I'm going to want to review the source material to determine how best to revise that part of my answer.