# Regular expression Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have this code with regular expression:

```
read string

regex="^[1-9][0-9]*\+[1-9][0-9]+$"

if [[ "$string" =~ $regex ]]; then

  echo "it's ok"

fi
```

Regular expression works for me, but when I insert a string with initial space , for example " 9+2", it should not recognize it(because in the regex I say it that the string must start with a number and not a space) but it print "it's ok" although it should not.

Why? what wrong in this code?

Comment: How does this work for you? The regex operator is `=~` not `~=`. Is this your real code?

Comment: it's because I don't copy and paste the code and it's a my mistake. sorry

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `read` removes the initial spaces so when the regex runs the value of `$string` is just `9+2` with no initial space. If you set the `$string` variable directly in your script instead of using userinput using `read` it should work.

More info on `read`'s behavior  at the following stackoverflow question:

[Bash read line does not read leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689172/bash-read-line-does-not-read-leading-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

If you want `read` to keep leading and trailing spaces, then you need to set `IFS` to empty:

```
IFS= read string
regex="^[0-9]+\+[0-9]+$"
if [[ "$string" =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "it's ok"
fi
```

In the above, I also corrected the `~=` operator and modified the regex to agree with your examples.

The behavior of `read` can be seen more directly in the following examples:

```
$ echo " 9+2 " | { read s; echo ">$s<"; }
>9+2<
$ echo " 9+2 " | { IFS= read s; echo ">$s<"; }
> 9+2 <
```