# command `file` cannot open *.txt

Tags: bash

I am practising to use the command `read`:

```
$ ls * | while read line; do printf "test %s\n"  $line; done
test data1.txt
test data5.txt
test data6.txt
test data7.txt
```

It works properly, but

```
$ ls * | while read line; do file $line; done
data1.txt: cannot open `data1.txt' (No such file or directory)
data5.txt: cannot open `data5.txt' (No such file or directory)
data6.txt: cannot open `data6.txt' (No such file or directory)
data7.txt: cannot open `data7.txt' (No such file or directory)
data8.txt: cannot open `data8.txt' (No such file or directory)
```

The file names are legal

```
$ ls
data1.txt  data5.txt  data6.txt  data7.txt  data8.txt
```

What's the problem with my code.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why you wouldn't use `find` to do this and avoid, at all costs, piping `ls` which will only lead to pain and suffering.

Comment: I want to explore `read` @JNevill

Comment: @JNevill One good reason: `find` is a overkill for this job. `file *` will do.

Comment: I would explore it with something other than `ls` as an input. `ls` output is terribly fragile and is not going to be a good learning tool. At any rate though, I'm not able to replicate the issues you are facing on your second example. It works fine for me.

Comment: Well, your filenamess have any unprintable characters, like whitespaces, tabs or newlines? Can't reproduce: `touch data{1,5,6,7,8}.txt; ls data*.txt | while read line; do file $line; done` (or pro `find data*.txt -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do file $line; done`)

Comment: How were `dataX.txt` created?

Comment: Are you showing the exact output in each case?  `ls *` is going to show you the content of subdirectories, which `file` will fail to find.

Comment: Never parse `ls` : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Can you run ones `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape` and show us the output

Comment: See [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/4154375) and [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file ... line-by-line ...?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion is that your files are not called `"data1.txt"` but actually something more like `"data1.txt "`. Notice the subtle space at the end. This could easily be the result of a tiny typo in a script or so. It could also be the usage of unprintable characters. You can check this with `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape`.

Example:

```
$ touch "data1.txt "
$ touch "data2.txt"
$ echo "a" > "data3.txt "
$ ls data* | while read line; do file $line; done
data1.txt: cannot open (No such file or directory)
data2.txt: empty
data3.txt: cannot open (No such file or directory)

         ^
Notice the missing spaces
```

There are several problems with this single line:

1. [Never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
2. [Always quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
3. [`read` removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689172/bash-read-line-does-not-read-leading-spaces). *This is actualy the main problem here*

So, if you want to solve the `read` problem, you do:

```
$ ls data* | while IFS= read -r line; do file "$line"; done
data1.txt : empty
data2.txt: empty
data3.txt : ASCII text

         ^
Notice the spaces, this is due to read
```

But the proper way to do it would be:

```
$ for f in data*; do file "$f"; done
data1.txt : empty
data2.txt: empty
data3.txt : ASCII text
```