# Clear 2 newline characters from the end of a file

Tags: c, file, input, output

I have a text file myfile.txt, and at the very bottom of it I have.

> Thanks for reading, goodnight.\n\n

How would I remove those 2 newline characters? I can open the file for writing, but can't figure out how to remove just those 2 from the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Just truncate the file by 2 characters:

```
int fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY);
fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(fp);
close(fd);
truncate("file.txt", sz - 2);
```

You are supposed to leave at lease one new line character at the end of a text file, but it isn't a requirement:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916758/1072647

Comment: None that I know of. And for sure it doesn't force such a restriction. Just try `printf "word" > text-file`

Comment: @Diego try doing a hexdump. There is a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: You used `echo` not `printf`. It's different

Comment: There is no need to have \n at the end of text file in Linux. Here is simple way to verify that. If you execute in terminal `cat > testfile` type in few characters and execute Ctrl+D and again Ctrl+D testfile will receive content. Now in terminal execute `file testfile` and output is `testfile: ASCII text, with no line terminators`

Comment: See [No final newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/) for a discussion of some of the problems you can run into if your 'text file' does not end with a newline.  You should avoid text files without a final newline.  Core Unix doesn't care; some of the text processing tooling does care.

Comment: See also: [**Why should files end with a newline?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline)