# Issue with reading file content using linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read contents of a file using a linux shell script. The contents of `file_list.txt` is:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

And the script to read this is `read_file_content.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(cat file_list.txt)
do
 "processing "$file
done
```

When I run the command as ./read_file_content.sh, I get the following error:

```
./read_file_content.sh: line 6: processing abc: command not found
./read_file_content.sh: line 6: processing def: command not found
./read_file_content.sh: line 6: processing ghi: command not found
```

Why does this print 'command not found'?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I tried using while loop but its not reading the last line from the file

Comment: I guess yours isn't a valid text file, then. Working around that is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line

Comment: thanks triplee, its working!

Comment: using 
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do echo $line; done < y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `"processing "$file` without any command in front of it.
Bash will take this literally and try to execute it as a command.
To print the text on the screen, you can use echo or printf.

**Echo example**

```
echo "processing" "$file"
```

**Printf example**

```
printf "%s\n" "$file"
```

(This is the recommend way if you're going to process weird filenames that contain - and space characters. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/43400))

Notice the way I did the quotes, this prevents problems with filenames that contain special characters like stars and spaces.