# Last row of file is getting truncated

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

last row of file is getting truncated

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filetouse=$1
while read -r STUDENTID FIRST LAST C1 C2 C3 
do
    totalSum=$(expr $C1 + $C2 + $C3)
    average=$(expr $totalSum / 3)
    printf '%d [%d] %s, %s\n' "$average" "$STUDENTID" "$LAST" "$FIRST"
done < "$filetouse" | sort -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k 2,2g
```

expected output =

```
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey
93 [928441032] Forester, Chris
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess
92 [888111818] Forney, JC
82 [123456789] Johnson, Lee
99 [290010111] Lee, Terry
91 [999999999] Smith, Jaime
```

actual output =

```
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess
92 [888111818] Forney, JC
82 [123456789] Johnson, Lee
99 [290010111] Lee, Terry
91 [999999999] Smith, Jaime
```

I noticed from the code that

```
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess
```

is missing. It also happens that its the last row of the file. But I'm not sure why the last line is truncated.

File I'm using = 
testing.sh

```
123456789 Lee Johnson 72 85 90
999999999 Jaime Smith 90 92 91
888111818 JC Forney 100 81 97
290010111 Terry Lee 100 99 100
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82
928441032 Jess Forester 85 80 82
928441032 Chris Forester 97 94 89
```

Comment: Check if your input file has `DOS CRLF` endings and remove them, it might mess up the bash loop

Comment: You're probably missing the line ending (newline) after the last line.  It's Chris Forester, not Jess Forester, who's missing.  See also [Shell script read missing last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line/).  I think this is probably a duplicate of that; if the last newline is missing, it will be confirmed.

Comment: please check your $IFS environment variable.

Comment: `while read -r STUDENTID FIRST LAST C1 C2 C3 || test -n "$C3"` will allow you to read the last line in the absence of a POSIX line-ending. (e.g. the `'\n'`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, that worked!

Comment: Funny how them old-timers have a trick or two left up their sleeves `;p`

Answer (score 0):

I run your script with no modification, got this:

```
#./script.sh input.txt 
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey
82 [123456789] Johnson, Lee
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess
91 [999999999] Smith, Jaime
92 [888111818] Forney, JC
93 [928441032] Forester, Chris
99 [290010111] Lee, Terry
```

It does show the one with 93.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your input file and script, I got correct result.

I also tried with changing input file format:
1) "DOS CRLF" will make script show error message.
2) a new line at end also make script show error message.

you'd better use `-x` option to show what happened when run script on your PC.

Plese run "echo $IFS" to show whether bash process newline correctly.