# Why is this regex not catching the last line of a file?

Tags: regex, bash

I read a text file line by line in a bash script, the goal is to catch variable declarations.

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filePath=$1

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[[:blank:]]*([^#[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*(.*) ]]
    then
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        echo "$var=$value"
    fi
done < "$filePath"
```

With this text file (note that the line "c=3" is the last line of the file):

```
# First variable
a=1
# Second variable
 b = 2
# Third variable
c=3
```

The output is:

```
a=1
b=2
```

But with this one:

```
# First variable
a=1
# Second variable
 b = 2
# Third variable
c=3
# empty line
```

The output is:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

It can be an empty line at the end, not necessary a comment.

Can someone explain why the last line is not catched by the regex in the first example? And how can I fix the problem (except from adding an empty line at the end of the text file...)? Thanks

Comment: Does your first file have a linebreak at the end? (Test with `cat -A`, check for end-of-line markers.) I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: And if this is the problem, the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line: `while read line || [[ -n $line ]]`

Comment: Wow! This is it, and your solution works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, it's not mine, I just knew it existed ;)

Comment: More fundamentally, maybe ask yourself if this makes sense as a Bash script. Perhaps Awk would be more versatile as well as straightforward.

Comment: @tripleee maybe you're right, but what I shown is just a part of a bigger script, and I believe bash is a correct choice. Furthermore, I didn't wrote it in the first place !

Answer (score 0):

for `while read line; do ... ; done`your file need end with a newline.

try:

`while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do`

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: thanks, you right... im edited my post...

Comment: But then you still don't read the last line if it doesn't end with a newline character, so you need `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do`

Comment: ...and then you have the exact answer from the duplicate ;)

Comment: yeap, you right again)