# How to append filename to each text file listed in... a text file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file, `itemlist.txt`, which is comprised of a list of strings like so:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
...
```

Each string corresponds to a text file (all with the same file extension) in the same directory as the list. In other words, `Item1` in the list signifies `Item1.txt` in the same directory, and so forth.

What is an efficient method to use this list to edit each file, appending the filename of each file to itself using a Bash shell script? In other words, "Item1" should be the last line of Item1.txt, etc.

I have GUI-based workflow tools to further manipulate these text files once the strings are in place, but I have a LOT to learn about Bash and this has stumped me. Ideally I would like to write a script that accepts user-defined arguments to write to the files along with the filename, but... baby steps!

I think `sed` is better for this than `echo`, in terms of manipulating the text files, but I am having trouble looping through the text file properly.

Comment: try `sed 's/.*/&.txt/' inputfile`  or `awk '$0=$0 ".txt"' input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `read` loop for this:

```
while read -r item; do
  file="$item.txt"
  [[ ! -f "$file" ]] && continue # skip if file doesn't exist or if it is not a regular file
  printf '%s\n' "$item" >> "$file"
done < itmelist.txt
```

Comment: This works well in the general case with test data. When I apply it to my specific case, I run into an issue (I think) because the actual text files are named such that line 2 needs to look like `file="$item_foo.txt"' where foo is the same for the whole batch. However, this code doesn't work (I guess the underscore needs to be escaped?). If I add '_foo' to the end of an item in the text file, it works.

Comment: `file="${item}_foo.txt"` would do it.

Comment: It certainly does!

Comment: Great.  `"$item\_foo.txt"` wouldn't work because `_` has no special meaning to shell and trying to escape it would result in literal `\_`.

Comment: In case anyone finds the code here useful for their own work, note that you may run into the issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line if your itemlist.txt file does not end with a newline. The solution there worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

echo is probably the easiest since you want to append

```
while read f; do
    echo "$f" >>"$f.txt"
done <itemlist.txt
```