# How to get bash IFS to pick up the last file in a list without requiring a newline

Tags: bash, shell, loops, sh, ifs

[At this link, the author discusses looping to read files from a list.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r file
do
  [ -f "$file" ] && rm -f "$file"
done < "/tmp/data.txt"
```

The problem is, the source file seems to require a newline following the last line it reads.

/tmp/data.txt

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt // <- if there is no newline, this file will not be read
```

If no newline exists after the last file, it will not be read.

/tmp/data.txt

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
// <- this newline, now makes file3.txt able to be read
```

Is there a way to cleanly rewrite the code to pick up the last line `file3.txt` regardless of whether or not a newline follows it?

Edit:

The answer pointed to in the comment solves the problem. Added `|| [ -n "$file" ];` to the `while` statement. The code is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r file || [ -n "$file" ];
do
  [ -f "$file" ] && rm -f "$file"
done < "/tmp/data.txt"
```

Comment: Sorry about the chattiness of the dupe. The relevant answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919766/1899640)

Comment: The answer solves it. For the curious, the code that solved my problem is `while IFS= read -r file || [ -n "$file" ];`