# Iterate over grep output in multi-line chunks

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I can't figure out how to iterate by match from grep output when using -A or -B flags (returning multiple lines for a single match). I'm not opposed to using awk for this, but this will be used to check multiple large files so the shorter execution time, the better.

I figured I could achieve this by using --group-separator flag of grep and setting IFS to the same character, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
$ grep --group-separator=@ -B2 'locked' thisisatest | while IFS=@ read -r match; do 
echo "a" 
echo "${match}"
done
a
this is a test file asdflksdklsdklsdkl.txt
a
this is meaningless
a
this is locked
a

a
this is a test file basdflksdklsdklsdkl.txt
a
this is meaningless
a
this is locked

$ cat thisisatest
this is a test file asdflksdklsdklsdkl.txt
this is meaningless
this is locked
j
j
j
j
j
this is a test file basdflksdklsdklsdkl.txt
this is meaningless
this is locked
```

I expect "a" to be printed before and after the entirety of a match such as:

```
a
this is a test file asdflksdklsdklsdkl.txt
this is meaningless
this is locked
a
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `$IFS` controls how `read` splits a line into fields. You're only having it fill out one field at a time (`$match`), so the field delimiter doesn't matter. Change the line delimiter instead: use `read -d`.

```
grep ... | while read -d@ -r match; do
```

Comment: It seems that the last result isn't caught in the `$match`.

Comment: Looking at the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916758/8543203), appending a `|| [ -n "$match" ]` after `while read` fixed the issue above.