# Missing last line in file

Tags: bash

Using the code below. It will not copy the last line in the file.

I have tried the following means of reading the file.

> "while IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a myLine" or "while IFS=$'\n' read -r -a myLine"

```
while read -a myLine
do
  for ((i=0;i<"${#myLine[@]}";i++))
  do
    temp_array[$i]+=" ${myLine[$i]}"
  done
done < $1
```

File contains numbers like:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

when echo is used to see what is in the array i get

```
1 2
3 4
```

this is where it drops off the last line.

Comment: Is the last line in your file terminated by a newline?

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C your_file` to your question.

Comment: @melpomene no there is no termination of /n. the files vary and the code needs to account for with or without newline.

Comment: A file without a newline by definition is not a POSIX text file and so YMMV trying to run POSIX tools that read text files on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Bash 4:

```
mapfile -t MyArray < "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the last line, `read` hits the end of file rather an an end-of-line delimiter (newline character), so it returns a failure status and the loop exits. But it *does* put the content it read into the array variable, so check for that to make it process that last line:

```
while read -a myLine || [[ ${#myLine[@]} -gt 0 ]]
do
```

This is very similar to the [solution for `read` without `-a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line/12919766#12919766); the only difference is how to test for a nonempty line after the last linefeed.