# How to store two strings which includes spaces separated by a comma into two separate files in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, while-loop

second time posting here. I apologize if I make any mistakes in my formatting. 
I have a file that contains a US State and its respective capital city next to it separated by a comma.

```
Alabama,Montgomery
Alaska,Juneau
Arizona,Phoenix
Arkansas,Little Rock
California,Sacramento
Colorado,Denver
```

I am trying to separate the state and city into two separate files and have managed to come up with this,

```
for line in $(cat file);do
    capital=$(echo $line | cut -d , -f2)
    state=$(echo $line | cut -d , -f1)
    echo $capital >> capitals
    echo $state >> states
done
```

The problem with this code is that even though I've set the cut delimiter to a comma, the program seems to have space still as a delimiter for cities that contains a space (ex. Little Rock).

With the program I have above, my capitals file contains,

```
Montgomery
Juneau
Phoenix
Little
Rock
Sacramento
Denver
```

Notice how *Little Rock* is in two separate lines and not in the same line.
**How can I modify my program to have it in the same line?** I've tried setting IFS to a comma, but when I do, my capitals file also contains the states.

```
Alabama
Montgomery
Alaska
Juneau
Arizona
Phoenix
Arkansas
Little Rock
California
Sacramento
Colorado
Denver
```

Comment: The problem is that `for line in $(cat file)` splits on whitespace, including spaces as well as newlines. See the BashFAQ entry ["Why you don't read lines with `for"`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Use `while IFS=, read -r capital state; do` with input from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create six child processes for each single line of the input. If the input file gets really large, this will cost a lot of wall clock time. I would do

```
cut -d , -f2 file > capitals
cut -d , -f1 file > states
```

Comment: Whoa I never even though of that hahaha. I guess I was just over complicating things.

Comment: Of course for really huge input files (or files being read over a slow network), the answer given by RavinderSingh13 is better than mine, since he needs only one process, while mine needs two.

Comment: @user1934428, This will also create 2 processes, but good solution, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  out_city="city_output_file"
  out_state="state_output_file"
}
{
  print $1 > (out_state)
  print $2 > (out_city)
}
'  Input_file
```

***With `bash`:***

```
while IFS=, read -r  state city;
do
   echo "$state" >> "state_output_file"
   echo "$city" >> "city_output_file"
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried running the program but it says "awk: cannot open Input_file (No such file or directory)"

Comment: @KillahBeans, it will give, since you need to put your actual file name in place of Input_file, put it and it should fly then.

Comment: Just tried out the bash version and it works. However, I noticed that Colorado,Denver was skipped during the while loop as it is missing in the two output files.

Comment: @KillahBeans, both solutions worked fine for me, how about `awk` command?

Comment: Ah nevermind. I managed to fixed it using the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line. I guess it's because the last line did not end with a new line. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

While `awk` is fine for this problem, you really should also understand how to read the file in a shell script and use *parameter expansions* to trim the unwanted text from each line to isolate the state and capital and write each to their respective files.

It is a basic bread and butter part of shell scripting. (and quite easy here) For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

states=${2:-states}         ## states as 2nd argument (default "states")
capitals=${3:-capitals}     ## capitals as 3rd argument (default "capitals")

:>$states       ## truncate both files
:>$capitals

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "${line%,*}" >> "$states"     ## trim line from right to 1st comma
    echo "${line#*,}" >> "$capitals"   ## trim line from left to 1st comma
done < "$1"
```

(**note:** the script reads from the filename provided as the first argument to the program and writes to the state and capital files optionally provided as the 2nd and 3rd arguments)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
Alabama,Montgomery
Alaska,Juneau
Arizona,Phoenix
Arkansas,Little Rock
California,Sacramento
Colorado,Denver
```

**Example Use**

```
$ bash separate.sh file
```

**Resulting Output Files**

States:

```
$ cat states
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Colorado
```

Capitals:

```
$ cat capitals
Montgomery
Juneau
Phoenix
Little Rock
Sacramento
Denver
```

`awk` will be faster, but the script above will be orders of magnitude more efficient than your original attempt that spawns multiple subshells per-iteration piping output to `cut`. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Adding The Combined File**

I guess you would also want a combined file for both state and capital on separate lines. Simply add another file for the output, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

states=${2:-states}         ## states as 2nd argument (default "states")
capitals=${3:-capitals}     ## capitals as 3rd argument (default "capitals")
combined=${4:-combined}     ## combined as 4th argument (default "combined")

:>$states       ## truncate all files
:>$capitals
:>$combined

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "${line%,*}" >> "$states"     ## trim line from right to 1st comma
    echo "${line#*,}" >> "$capitals"   ## trim line from left to 1st comma
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "${line%,*}" "${line#*,}" >> "$combined"
done < "$1"
```

(**note:** adding `|| [ -n "$line" ]` to your `while` loop condition will handle the last line without a POSIX end-of-file (`'\n'` at end of last line))

**Resulting Output Files**

Combined:

```
$ cat combined
Alabama
Montgomery
Alaska
Juneau
Arizona
Phoenix
Arkansas
Little Rock
California
Sacramento
Colorado
Denver
```

Comment: You had `awk` completely covered -- no meat left on the bone there `:)` Good job.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create six child processes for each single line of the input. If the input file large then its useful

```
awk -F ',' '{print $(NF-1)}' > capital file
awk -F ',' '{print $NF}' > states file
```