# why git log output redirect to a while loop not working?

Tags: bash, git

I am trying this command in my bash shell script:

```
git log --oneline --no-decorate  --pretty=format:"%s" $oldrev..$newrev

git log --oneline --no-decorate  --pretty=format:"%s" $oldrev..$newrev | while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

the first git log can print output, but the second one followed by while won't print anything. why ?

I invoke my script like this:( second and third argument passed to $oldrev and $newrev)

```
./check master a735c2f eb23992
```

if I add --no-pager option, both will print nothing.

I am using bash 4.4.23(1)-release on fedora 28.

Comment: It does seem to work as expected for me.

Comment: Where are you setting the args in the shell script?

Comment: apparently, the double period represent the commit range causing my trouble, but still don't know why.

Comment: For whichever reason, your `git` command does not output a trailing linefeed when piped, so you need to [read a stream that fails to terminate its last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line)

Comment: @thatotherguy excellent! I append a %n to git log format proved you are right.

Comment: Or, use `--pretty=tformat:...` which adds a terminating newline if needed.

Comment: btw, just `--pretty=` defaults to `tformat`.  `--pretty=%s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `pretty=format`, you should use [`pretty=tformat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-trailersoptions):

> '`tformat:`'
>
> The '`tformat:`' format works exactly like '`format:`', except that it provides "terminator" semantics instead of "separator" semantics.
>
> In other words, each commit has the message terminator character (usually a newline) appended, rather than a separator placed between entries.
>
> This means that the final entry of a single-line format will be properly terminated with a new line, just as the "oneline" format does. For example:
>
> ```
> $ git log -2 --pretty=format:%h 4da45bef \
>   | perl -pe '$_ .= " -- NO NEWLINE\n" unless /\n/'
> 4da45be
> 7134973 -- NO NEWLINE
>
> $ git log -2 --pretty=tformat:%h 4da45bef \
>   | perl -pe '$_ .= " -- NO NEWLINE\n" unless /\n/'
> 4da45be
> 7134973
> ```
>
> In addition, any unrecognized string that has a `%` in it is interpreted as if it has `tformat:` in front of it.
>   For example, these two are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $ git log -2 --pretty=tformat:%h 4da45bef
> $ git log -2 --pretty=%h 4da45bef
> ```