# read fails with set -eou pipefail

Tags: bash

I have script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# exit when any command fails
set -euo pipefail

api_key="${POWERDNS_API_KEY}"
dns_server_addr="127.0.0.1"
server_id="localhost"
zone_id="${K8S_FQDN_SUFFIX}."
prefix="$1"
ip="$2"

read -rd '' payload << EOF
{
    "rrsets": [
        {
            "name": "$prefix.svc.${K8S_FQDN_SUFFIX}.",
            "type": "A",
            "changetype": "REPLACE",
            "ttl": 10,
            "records": [
                {
                    "content": "$ip",
                    "disabled": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF

curl -i -H "X-API-Key: $api_key" -X PATCH --data "$payload" \
"http://$dns_server_addr:8081/api/v1/servers/$server_id/zones/$zone_id"
```

It fails on `read -rd '' payload` without message. If I remove `set -euo pipefail` everything works fine. What I do wrong? Actually I don't even need `set -euo pipefail`, just interesting why this happens.

Comment: Do read the "lots of messy exceptions" link in Gordon's answer. `set -e` seems like a good idea... until you dig into the details of how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` command tries to read a single line from standard input. If it fails for any reason -- including hitting the end-of-file before seeing a line terminator -- it exits with a nonzero status. In your case, the `-d ''` option tells `read` to look for an ASCII null character as the line terminator, and since the here-document doesn't have one it reads until it hits EOF... and then exits with an error status.

`read`'s behavior may be a bit counterintuitive here. It read something successfully, and set the variable (`payload`) just fine; but since it hit EOF it's required by the POSIX standard to return an error. The exact same thing happens when reading a text file line-by-line, and [the last line isn't terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line).

Normally this wouldn't be a big deal, but the `-e` option to `set` makes the shell exit if any simple command exits with a nonzero (error) status (with [lots of messy exceptions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) that aren't relevant here). When `read` does that, the script exits on the spot.

So, there are a few possible solutions. You could just not use `set -e`, you could put `set +e` just before the `read` command (and maybe `set -e` again afterward), or you could make it a compound command that'll succeed, like this:

```
read -rd '' payload << EOF || true
...
```

(Here, the `||` means if the first command fails it'll run the second, and `true` always succeeds, so the compound command is considered to succeed.)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot.