# Loop two files specified from input parameters simultaneously failed

Tags: bash, shell

In a shell script, if I specify directly the text file, it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=''
while read input <&3 && read output <&4; do     
    echo "$input -----> $output"
done 3<inputfile.txt 4<outputfile.txt #This line works
```

However, when I try to make the script accept arguments (`./myscript.sh inputfile.txt outputfile.txt`), there's nothing echoed:

```
#!/bin/bash

fromtxt="$1"
totext="$2"
IFS=''
while read input <&3 && read output <&4; do     
    echo "$input -----> $output"
done 3<"$fromtxt" 4<"$totext" #This line doesn't
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: It works when I test it. I'd recommend adding `set -x` at the beginning, so it'll print the commands as it executes them and you can get some idea what's happening.

Comment: I didn't realize about `set -x` until today, thank you. It seems like I'm having missing last line issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line.

Comment: Hmm. The order of precedence of `||` and `&&` isn't going to be helpful in combining that with what you have. Try `while { read input <&3 || [ -n "$input" ]; } && { read output <&4 || [ -n "$output" ]; }; do`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can avoid looping with `awk` or with a solution like

```
paste -d "\r" inputfile.txt outputfile.txt| sed 's/\r/ ------> /'
```