# How to run a command from a variables output once per line? -- bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop, scripting

thank you for taking time to help!

I'm trying to run a command 1 time with a variable as the argument. The thing is, the variable has multiple lines, and I need to run a command 1 time for each line as the argument.

Example script

```
VAR1=command1

"${VAR1}" | xargs -L1 -d "\n command2$i
```

The example output for VAR1 is

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
```

I need to run command2 one time per line, so

```
command2 1111
command2 2222
command2 3333
command2 4444
command2 5555
```

I have tried this as well,

```
VAR1=command1

"${VAR1}" | while read line ; do command2$i
```

and this

```
VAR1=command1

"${VAR1}" | while read line ; do command2"${VAR1}"
```

Thank you for yalls time!

Comment: What is `$i`? It should be `do command2 "$line"`

Comment: And you need a space after `command2`

Comment: You also forgot `;done`

Comment: `"${VAR1}" | while read -r line ; do command2 "$line"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For xargs, you can use a "here string":

```
xargs -L1 command2 <<< "$var1"
```

or simply

```
printf '%s\n' "$var1"  | xargs -L1 command2
```

And similarly for the loop, but you need to really use the loop variable:

```
while read -r line ; do
    command2 "$line"
done <<< "$var1"
```

or, again,

```
printf '%s\n' "$var1" | while read -r line ; do
    command2 "$line"
done
```

Comment: You might need to use `printf '%s\n'` if the variable doesn't include a terminating newline. (On the other hand, `<<< "$var1"` *does* append a newline, so if the variable has a terminating newline you'll get a blank line at the end.)

Comment: @gordondavisson I tested the solution and it seems to work without the newline.

Comment: `xargs` will tolerate a missing final linefeed (at least the versions I tested do), but [`while read` won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: You're right, I had an error in my tests.