# bash cd in function is not working with pipe

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, pipe, cd

I want pipe to cd by define a mycd function, expect using like this: **echo workspace | mycd**

this is how my function look like:

```
mycd(){
  read path
  cd $path && ls #The problem is (cd path) didn't get into the path, but (&& ls) is working good.
}
```

my test below shows that case 1 not able to change the path, but case 2 do.

```
1.
~ $ echo workspace | mycd
~ $ 

2.
~ $ mycd
workspace
~/workspace $
```

Comment: Pipe isn't always a valid solution for the problem. `read` [has it's quirks that you may not know about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line), so your program will fail when you least expect it.

Instead of piping you could use command substitution `cd $(someCommand)`.
You could also use `PWD=$(...) command` for one-time command in pipe.

Answer (score 0):

A bash function runs in a subshell and the path is changed in that process. That's why `ls` shows the contents of the directory.
However, when the function exits you see that your original shell is still using the old path.
See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1379728/when-i-change-working-directory-in-a-script-and-execute-it-the-working-director) for more information.

You can accomplish what you want with an alias:

```sh
alias mycd='read path && cd "$path" && ls'
echo workspace | mycd
~/workspace $
```

Make sure you use single quotes, with double quotes the variable `$path` will get expanded (to nothing) when the alias is defined.

Comment: This can't work. Have you tested it on Bash before posting here?

Answer (score -2):

read sets response into a variable, so your code should look like

```
mycd(){
  read path
  cd "$path" && ls
}
```

After that your code will work, i hope i helped

Comment: Path is only changed in the subshell running the function. You can't run a shell command like that and change the parent shell.

Comment: sorry for miss the $ right before path,  already edit the question.

Comment: @micke: There's no subshell.