# What does the [ -n "$URL" ] option do in this script?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="urls.txt"
URL=""

while read URL || [ -n "$URL" ] ;
do
  echo -e "
*************************************************************************************
Scaning \"$URL\" ...
*************************************************************************************\n";
  nmap -v -sV $URL -Pn |tee $URL-$(date +%m%d%y)_$(date +%H%M).log
done < $INPUT
```

I know that if I just remove `|| [ -n "$URL" ]`, the script won't process the last line of `$INPUT`.

Also, could you please explain me where is the part of the script in which you go to the next line of `$INPUT` in each step of the `while` loop?

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=while+read+URL+%7C%7C+%5B+-n+%22%24URL%22+%5D%3B+do+echo+%22%24URL%22%3B+done

Comment: `read` reads the next line of input each time it runs (which is at the beginning of each iteration of the loop). As for the `-n` part, see ["Shell script read missing last line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line).

Comment: You find this documented, when you do a `man test`.

Comment: @user1934428 `man [` will work as well

Comment: @phuclv : I would had expected this too, but interestingly it does not work in my installation (Cygwin). In particular, `man [` does not show me the _test_ man page, but just refers to the page _BASH_BUILTINS(1)_, which does not give any information on this command. This is odd, since both `[` and `test` are bash builtins and at the same time available as external commands, so I would have expected that `man` behaves identical for them.

Answer (score 0):

So, **final answer** would be that `[ -n "$STRING" ]` will return `TRUE` if the variable `“$STRING”` has non-zero length.  So what is the magic beyond this?

**(1) First of all, what does read VARIABLE do?**

It reads the actual line (first character from line to first occurrence of new line reserved character `\n` or `EOF`, which is the reserved character for `END OF FILE`). The thing with this sentence is that it returns `TRUE` only if the actual line ends with `\n`, but not with some specific `EOF` characters (it should, but some text editors use a different reserved character and it won’t work always).

**PD:** Every time `read` command is executed, it moves an internal pointer to the next line of `$INPUT`. So, what happens after `read` command reads the last line on `INPUT` (the one that ends with `EOF`)? It will return `FALSE` and `VARIABLE` will be returned empty.

**(2) How does the last while iteration takes place?**

First take a look at the condition: `while read URL || [ -n "$URL" ] ;`
So, because it is the last iteration, the actual line will end with `EOF` character. Therefore `read URL` will return `FALSE` (because line doesn’t end with `\n`), but `URL` won’t be empty, because there is an actual url there. This way, the first term of the `while` condition will be `FALSE`, but because `URL` is not empty, second term will be `TRUE`, which makes the whole condition to be `TRUE`. So, last line of `INPUT` will be processed as it should, despite having a weird `EOF` character.