# Why is my script cutting off the last input value?

Tags: bash, echo

I have this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
OLD_IFS=$IFS
counter=0

while [ $counter -lt 2 ] && IFS= read -r -p "Enter row $(($counter+1)): " row; do
    echo "whole row: $row"
    while read -d " " char; do 
    echo "$char"
    done <<<$row
((counter++))
done

IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

It's cutting off the last field from my input, but I don't understand why:

INPUT:

```
./ex8.07.sh 
Enter row 1: 1 2 3 4 5
```

OUTPUT:

```
whole row: 1 2 3 4 5
1
2
3
4
Enter row 2:
```

Why can't it access digit 5 in the second "while" loop?

Comment: Because there's no space after the last number, and `-d " "` looks for a space delimiter.

Comment: `read -d " " char` *fails* at reading an entire row if there's no terminating space, even if it "partially" succeeds at reading at least one character. Use `read` as it is intended, to read a *line* of text, then split the space-separated line into multiple characters.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/6rjoN0ajO Works for me

Comment: (You can use `read -a row` to read an entire row into a single *array*, for example.)

Comment: This is the same basic problem as ["Shell script read missing last line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line/) (except that the missing delimiter is a space instead of a newline).

Comment: Thanks to all replies. Workaround by adding extra space at the end in var row

Answer (score 3):

The reason it won't show you the last element of `$row` is that it's splitting on spaces, and there's no space after the last number.

If you re-wrote the herestring as `<<<"$row "` it would work. IMO this is ugly.

If you made sure to enter a spacebar after the last number it would also work. IMO this isn't user-friendly.

However, might I suggest using an array instead? Bash's arrays are perfect for this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
# Split on all shell word separators (any number of spaces and/or tabs)
while [[ $counter -lt 2 ]] && read -r -p "Enter row $(($counter+1)): " -a row; do
    # Note the first char of IFS is the "glue" character (default: ' ')
    echo "whole row: ${row[*]}"

    for char in "${row[@]}"; do
        echo "$char"
    done
    ((counter++))
done
```

I suppose you could set `IFS=' '`  to only have it break only on spaces (i.e. `IFS=' ' read -r -p "Enter row $(($counter+1)): " -a row`), but that's up to you.

Of note is that running `IFS=... read -r ...` DOESN'T clobber IFS in the local scope, it only modifies IFS for that one invocation of the `read` built-in.

### Another Way

I wrote this utility function for a [larger script I wrote](https://codeberg.org/h3xx/pip2tgz):

```bash
split_array() {
    local -n ARR=$1
    local -r DELIM=$2
    readarray -d "$DELIM" -t ARR
    # XXX Here-strings (<<<) add a newline
    # --> Workaround: strip newlines from the end of the last entry
    ARR[-1]=${ARR[-1]%$'\n'}
}
```

The syntax is a little funky but it works:

```bash
# Sets MYNUMBERS to an indexed array of strings. Access using ${MYNUMBERS[@]}
split_array MYNUMBERS ' ' <<<'one two three four'
```